# testing the hello world application on a different computer when the compute crashes/node not working

Tags: blockchain

I am new to the blockchain technology. I want to test the blockchain functionality of a decentralized ledger.

I have created a hello world smart contract(on solidity, geth, mist browser) on computer A. Now I want to bring down the geth console on computer A and then start the geth console on computer B and test if I can see the hello world smart contract on computer B. what is the process to test this functionality? kindly help

Answer (score 0):

First you need to run mist on computer B and import your wallet keystore file.
Second, To import a contract you need to go into the mist and click **contracts**-->**watch contract**, Then you need to give your **contract address**, **contract Name** and paste the **json code** in the **json interface** and click **ok**. See below:[image: Import contract]

Comment: I want to test this scenario: I have create hello world smart contract(solidity) on private ethereum node. If computer A crashes and I do not have any contract address, json interface etc. I should be able to sync computer A with computer B. My Questions: How to sync the blocks? How can the two machines see each other as peers? If there are any changes done on computer A, I should be able to see the changes in the computer B. So that if computer A crashes, I should be able to continue with computer B as I have synced the blocks. I want to know what is the process to do this.